# What’s the equation behind this strange curve?

Tags: functions

I have come across a strange kind of curve, which I can’t imagine what is the equation behind. I’ve tried a variety of approaches, from numerically calculating the derivative and second (and so on) derivative$\ldots$ but that gave me no clue about the very nature of this curve.

[image: Strange curve]

@user21820: The data can be found on pastebin [here].(http://pastebin.com/UbhmETsd)

This sequence of points seems to grow with a slope of exactly 1 until the slope decreases to zero quite sharply$\ldots$ I numerically calculated the first three derivatives of this curve:

The first derivative looks like:

[image: first derivative]

Interestingly (I think), the first derivative’s “turning point” is at $x=500$, just like the $y$ maxima of the function I a looking for$\ldots$ This is numerically verified by the looks of the second derivative:

[image: second derivative]

Is the third derivative of any help? (Note that the grey line here should not to be considered.)

[image: third derivative]

Well$\ldots$ Hope you can help me!

N.B.: I can provide the raw data if necessary, but I felt this would render the question unreadable (2000 values$\ldots$)

**Edit 1:** @Ron: The plot of $f(x) = 500 \tanh(x/500)$ in red; and $f(x) = 500 \sqrt \tanh{((x/500)^2)}$ in green:

[image: tanh models]

**Edit 2:** @user21280: This is also very close but there seems to be a little discrepancie, again around the bending point.

[image: tanh integral]

**Edit 3:** The story behind this mysterious curve:
In a closed system with two compartments *A* and *B*, exchanges of some element *E* occurs between these two compartments. *A* is finite while *B* is not. Flux from *A* to *B* (`Fab`) in one unit of time is a fraction of stock of *E* in *A* (`Fab = 0.001 * A`). Flux from *B* to *A* is a fraction of stock of *E* in *B* times the fraction of free “space” in *A* (`Fba = 0.1 * B * (Amax-A)/Amax`).

Considering, at the start of simulation, that `A = 0` and `B = x`, for `x = 1:2000`, what is the value `y` of `B` at the equilibrium? (given `Amax = 500`)

[image: Beq]

When `B0` gets high enough, `A` is saturated and `B_eq (y)` increases as a linear function of `B0`. Hence the idea of substracting `B0` from `B_eq`. Which gives away my mysterious curve.

**Edit 4:** The reproducible `R` code behind:

```
Amax <- 500 # max stock of element in solid phase

A0 <- 0 # stock of element in solid phase (A) at time zero

niequ <- 1000   # time allowed for reaching equilibrium between A and B

rec <- c(0)

for(B0 in 1:2000){  # B0 = stock of element in B at time zero
    A <- A0

    B <- B0

    for(i in 1:niequ){
        
        Fab <- .001*A
        Fba <- 0.1*B*(1-A/Amax)
        B <- B - Fba + Fab
        A <- A  + Fba - Fab
        
    }
    rec <- c(rec,mean(B))
}
rec <- rec[-1]
plot(rec~c(1:length(rec)))  # B at equilibrium as a function of B at time zero

rec2 <- (rec-c(1:length(rec)))  # substraction of linear increase
rec2 <- -rec2 # for working with positive values (easier for me)

plot(x=c(1:length(rec)), y=rec2)    # the mysterious curve...
```

Comment: Where does the data come from? I don't think one always should expect that collected data can be represented by some very simple function. Of course one could come up with some "monster" that will fit it pretty good, but as I read it this is not what you look for?

Comment: @mickep: You are right, this is important and I will try to explain how I came across this curve in a few minutes.

Comment: Could you provide the numerical data? Use pastebin or something else.

Comment: Try some linear combination of these two suggestions. :)

Comment: Can you check how well the graph of the second derivative matches a (flipped) Gaussian curve?

Comment: @NikhilMahajan: done.

Comment: @Rahul - It drops too slow to be Gaussian. Too fast to be Lorentzian.

Comment: @Rodolphe: The data you've provided doesn't have enough significant digits to get a useful third derivative.

Comment: @NikhilMahajan: First, thanks for looking so deep into this datas. Actually, all values have 7 significant digits, although 'R' automatically drops all trailing zeroes.

Comment: Compare your plot for the third derivative with the one made from the data you provided: http://i.imgur.com/GpdiswK.png .

Most of the action happens around $x = 500$ but the data you've provided has only 4 decimal places around that part of the data. (Sorry, I didn't mean SIGNIFICANT DIGITS in the previous comment)

There is no way to get as smooth a plot as yours with the precision of the data you've provided on Pastebin.

Comment: State your source of the data.. The data fits too perfectly to a curve to be from real-world measurements.

Comment: @NikhilMahajan: OMG I have to recognize that's ugly. Sorry for that. Working on curating code for adding it to the question.

Comment: Code and story behind added.

Comment: Equilibrium occurs at $F_{ab}=F_{ba}$. Solve for $a$ and $b$ subject to the conservation of stock, $a+b=a_0+b_0=x$. You get $$a= \frac{1}{2} \left(x+505-\sqrt{x^2-990 x+255025}\right),\\b= \frac{1}{2} \left(x-505+\sqrt{x^2-990 x+255025}\right).$$

Comment: @Rahul: It seems you got the answer. Wow! Please consider posting this as an answer ? so I can accept it ? Maybe with slightly more steps ? Thanks.

Comment: @Rahul, Turns out I was twenty minutes behind, with an error as well.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, Rahul got it first and right. But your answer was useful also (after correction) for the "step by step" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At equilibrium,
$$F_{ab}=F_{ba}\\
0.001A = 0.1B(1-A/A_{\max.})\\
0.001A = 0.1(x-A)(1-A/A_{\max.})\\
0.01AA_{\max.}=(A-x)(A-A_{\max.})\\
A^2-(x+1.01A_{\max.})A+xA_{\max.}=0\\
A_\text{eq.} = \frac12\left(x+1.01A_{\max.}\pm\sqrt{x^2-1.98A_{\max.}x+1.0201A_{\max.}^2}\right)\\
A_\text{eq.} = \frac12\left(x+505\pm\sqrt{x^2-990x+255025}\right)\\
\text{(probably the negative square-root)}\\
y=x-A_\text{eq.} = \frac12\left(x-1.01A_{\max.}\mp\sqrt{x^2-1.98A_{\max.}x+1.0201A_{\max.}^2}\right)\\
y=\frac12\left(x-505\mp\sqrt{x^2-990x+255025}\right)\\
\text{(probably the positive square-root)}
$$

Comment: Please have a look to the answer I just gave.

Answer (score 2):

This to me seems like a hyperbolic tangent function:

$$f(x) = a \tanh{b x}$$

A quick inspection reveals that $a$ should be about $500$.  Perhaps the slope at $x=0$ being about $1.0$ would imply that $b=1/500$.  Obviously, these numbers should be taken with a grain of salt but at least represent a starting point for the analysis.  The functional form seems to at least match somewhat the derivative profiles.

**EDIT**

A comparison to the data showed that $f$ did not bend fast enough.  Another possibility is

$$g(x) = 500 \sqrt{\tanh{\left [\left (\frac{x}{500} \right )^2\right ]}}$$

A quick inspection shows that there is a better fit to the bending, although the behavior of the second derivative is a bit different.

Comment: Wait a minute, neither does your function fit. Your function fits the first derivative very well according to my experience of sigmoid functions.

Comment: @user21820: a plot of the second derivative reveals a bump below the axis as illustrated.  The only difference is that the second derivative has a nonzero slope at zero, but I feel this is a minor point.  The third derivative has the same general behavior as pictured.  The OP may wish to introduce additional parameters to improve the fit, but this is a good start.

Comment: @RonGordon: Your were closer than i never was with this equation, however it does not seem to "bend fast enough" when compared with the actual data. I added a plot of your equation for comparison.

Comment: @Rodolphe: see my edit, which accounts for the bending.

Comment: @RonGordon: edited the graph with adjusted equation in green.

Comment: @Rodolphe: Fine.  I hope you can see how I was able to refine my guess based on the fit, and perhaps you can further refine this result to get a simple function that you can use.

Comment: @RonGordon: Yes I think I understand. I will try to refine it through nonlinear estimate of exponent coefficient ? then post the edit

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a good reason for the data, but it looks like $x \mapsto \int_0^x \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\tanh(\frac{t-500}{100}) \right)\ dt$. It matches all the graphs perfectly as far as I can tell.

[Edit: After Rodolphe finally told the origin of the data...]

It can be seen that it is just a differential equation $\frac{da}{dt} = -pa+q(1-\frac{a}{m})(c-a)$ where $a$ is the amount in $A$, $c$ is the total amount in both, $m$ is the capacity of $A$ and $p,q$ are fixed parameters. The differential equation is separable and just requires integrating the reciprocal of a quadratic function, which is easy. I'm too lazy to do it though.

[Edit: After Rodolphe posted the code, it is clear that I misunderstood the process...]

Michael did it so I don't have to. Great!

Comment: This function would not have the second derivative profile shown.

Comment: @RonGordon: Oh yes.. Let me fix the differential equation then..

Comment: @RonGordon: See this now. =)

Comment: @Rodolphe: How does my guess compare? You might as well upload the data somewhere where we can get it...

Comment: @user21820: Yes I would like to upload it but I don't know how nor where, nor how to format it for you to use it (I use R programming language). As for your guess, I am currently working on it. back in a few minutes :-)

Comment: @Rodolphe: If you wanted, simply a list of points in a text file (perhaps on pastebin) so that we can plot in a graphing software. And yes please tell us the source.

Comment: @user21820: data posted on pastebin. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user21820: And I added your equation graph at the end of the question.

Comment: I think the $x$-axis is the total amount at the start, rather than time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is IMHO a slightly more direct approach.

Indeed, this curve with 2 neat asymptotes invites to consider it as a (branch of) **hyperbola** having a horizontal asymptote with approx. equation $y-500=0$ and a slant asymptote with approx. equation $y-x=0$. The common equation of all hyperbolas with such asymptotes is:

$$(y-500)(y-x)=k$$

where $k$ is constant (where the LHS is the product of the LHS of the asymptotes).

Forcing the curve to pass by a certain point $A(x_0,y_0)$ clearly fixes the value of the constant. If we fix (approx.) $A(1,0.9900796)$ (according to the given data), we obtain the following equation:

$$(y-500)(y-x)=k_0\tag{1}$$

If we expand (1) as a polynomial in $y$ with parameter $x$, we get a quadratic equation

$$y^2-(x+500)y+(500x-k_0)=0$$

whose solutions are:

$$y=\tfrac12 \left(x+500 \pm \sqrt{(x+500)^2-(500x-k_0)} \right)$$

finding back the solution given by others.

Remark: in fact the $\pm$ sign accounts for the two branches of the hyperbola. Clearly, we need to replace it by a minus sign in order to get the desired branch.